# How to perform incremental refresh based on modified date in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

Power BI Incremental refresh use case using the date created field is simple when there are no modifications or deletions to the data that is already loaded into the Power BI model.

I have a requirement where-in I need Incremental refresh with the ability to handle deletion and modifications.

For example: can I configure Incremental refresh on date modifed field, and suppose a record that was pulled in previous load is now modified in source thereby having a new Date modifed, then is the Incremental load able to delete the older record from the model when loading the new version of this row?

Similarly to handle situation where record is deleted from the source db?

If not supported by Power BI incremental refresh, then is there any way to handle such scenario in Power BI? Or I have to use the import full refresh mode only?

Comment: This is not supported with incremental refresh. If you need to query data that may still be modified and you can't afford loading all the data on refresh, you can consider Direct Query (and/or a hybrid table, combining DQ and aggregation), at the potential cost of some performance. The secret of Power BI's performance is loading all data in aggregated form into a columnstore. The resulting data access is very fast, especially for aggregations, but deleting or changing data in this form on a per-row basis is essentially not possible (or more accurate so costly that it's not worth it).

Answer (score 2):

Power BI can detect which partitions have modified rows with the "[Detect Data Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview)" setting.  Each partition will be queried to see if it contains any modified rows, and will be completely reloaded if it does.

Note you configure incremental refresh on some other date column, like SalesDate, and only use LastModifiedDate in change detection.  If you try to use LastModifiedDate as the partition key, rows will migrate between partitions, and you'll get inconsistent data if the source and destination partitions are not refreshed at the same time.

Comment: But the detect data changes concept is only applicable to the partitions in the Incremental range. Not in the archived range.

Comment: Yep.  If you have data change in the archival range it won’t detect.  But you can just incremental load all history with change detection, and old partitions that don’t have changes will not be refreshed.  So Change Detection is kind of an alternative to having Archival Partitions.

Comment: Is there a way with Incremental refresh where I can have no archival, and enable change detection so necessary partitions will reload?